# Switch won't recognize my wired Horipad+, but my PC does

Tags: technical-issues, controllers, nintendo-switch

My Switch doesn't recognize my [wired Horipad+](https://stores.horiusa.com/horipad-for-nintendo-switch-1/); when I plug it into my Switch dock, **the console does not recognize the controller and its status LEDs do not light up.** However, the controller works fine on my Windows PC.

Here are some relevant facts:

- My Switch recently came back from repairs. Its firmware is up to date.
- I have tried to use the controller with two different docks, with the same results in both cases.
- For both docks, I used different USB ports. (Remember, this is a wired controller.) No luck.
- I tested the controller in the Windows Devices and Printers menu, and it works fine. Buttons press, the stick moves, and everything.
- I know that Hori has a device manager Windows app for its controllers, but I haven't set it up yet.

Any tips?

Comment: You probably already have tried this, but: have you tried pressing L and R (or ZL and ZR) at the same time? I'm fairly sure I remember needing to do that when using 3rd party controllers (regardless of using cables or wireless).

Comment: Yes, no luck. But I did have luck doing something else! Something I should've seen coming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rebooting my Switch (*not* putting it in and out of sleep mode) solved the issue. Why didn't I think of that at the start? Who knows.

Comment: <Insert IT Crowd did you turn it off and on again meme here>

Comment: Heh, I had the exact same thing happen with my 8bitdo USB Adapters. Switch refused to recognize them. Tried upgrading/downgrading/factory reset the adapters - nothing. Finally tried rebooting the Switch itself and suddenly they worked perfectly again